# Why session start event fire randomly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have one site with lots of  session use.
Session time out is 20 mins and session management is InProcess.

Site is working fine
I have maintain log for the site...but in log file i got following notification

[10/31/2012 11:01:40 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:06:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:06:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:11:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:11:40 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:16:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:16:40 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:21:37 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:21:38 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:26:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:26:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:31:38 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:31:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:36:38 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:36:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:41:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:41:40 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:46:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:46:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:51:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:51:40 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start
[10/31/2012 11:56:39 PM]: Global.asax.Session_Start : Session Start

my application's session start event fire randomly, even nobody accessing the site
can anybody explain, what is the problem...?

Thanks in Adv....

Answer (score 0):

`Session_Start()` – fired when session starts on each new user requesting a page.
just check following link for more details:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the application goes out of memory means application pool recycle if it is idea for 20 minutes. 
And application again starts when someone request for your application.
Session start is called on every user first request.

Comment: Yes i know that very well, but in my case session start event is fire when nobody is accessing the site...and above log record is just small part of whole record....my application session start event is fire after every five minute...i dont understand WHY?

Comment: find the ip from where it is getting accessed. I don't have much of idea about it. You can go through you log file for that. As suggested by @patil

Comment: are you using a common application pool. Means the application pool which is used by your application is also used in other application?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are confident that nobody is accessing your application, you will have to double check that.
For this, go to IIS logs and find out if really no one is accessing your application.
You can get IIS logs from following location(these are default IIS log locations).

IIS 7:
**%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles**

IIS 6:
**%windir%\System32\LogFiles**